# How to pull our all inner text from website?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I pull out all inner text from page?

Please help

```
Sub CountryList()
    ' declare the variables
    Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer
    Dim htmlEle As IHTMLElement
    Dim i As Integer

    ' initialize i to one
    i = 1

    ' create and get access to an instance of IE
    Set ieObj = New InternetExplorer
    ieObj.Visible = True
    ieObj.navigate "http://www.spark-interfax.ru/system/home/card#/company/3411D127F25A45F7ABAB32964A32848D/250/latest"

    ' give the webpage some time to load all content
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    ' loop through all the rows in the table
    For Each htmlEle In ieObj.document.getElementsByclssName("div")(0).getElementsByclssName("sp-summary__text_pre").Innertext
        With ActiveSheet
            .Range("A" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(0).textContent
            .Range("B" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(1).textContent
            .Range("C" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(2).textContent
            .Range("D" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(3).textContent
            .Range("E" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(4).textContent
        End With

        i = i + 1
    Next htmlEle

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest you update your post to be more specific as to what your problem is and which info you want to pull from the webpage. Also, there is a typo here `.getElementsByclssName`. It should be `getElementsByClassName`. Furthermore, "div" is highly unlikely to be a class name. Maybe the method you should be using is `.getElementsByTagName("div")`.

Comment: Also, this `For Each htmlEle In ieObj.document.getElementsByclssName("div")(0).getElementsByclssName("sp-summary__text_pre").Innertext` is bound to fail, because you are basically trying to loop through a string, which doesn't make sense. What you need to do is loop through a collection of HTML elements. So you have to delete the `.innerText` part like so `For Each htmlEle In ieObj.document.getElementsByclssName("div")(0).getElementsByclssName("sp-summary__text_pre")`

Comment: Glad I could help! Did this solve your problem?